# Apache Solr and Object Oriented way "simulation"

Tags: solr, indexing

i have a tipical solr stuff: need of indexing documents, only that my documents are related to the topics, not associated with them in advance... in OO paradigm this scenario would be so described:

```
class Document { (List of Topic) topics, ... attrs } ; 
class Topic { (int) id, (String) name, ... attrs }
```

is there any way for indexing Topic independently from Document? (an update on topic, in this case is only for topic and not for all docs related with this topic)
considering that solr is focused on docs indexing...

thanks in advance, 
Enzo

Comment: What does "not associated in advance" mean?

Comment: mean that the association documents-topics takes place in a second time, after the documents have been indexed the first time, with an update

Comment: Why not associate them in memory *before* indexing, so there's only one indexing process?

Comment: ok this is fine, but about the indexing of the topic? can be indexed topic entities (that aren't docs) with Solr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the [Solr Join](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join) feature, introduced as a part of the [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2272) and available as a part for Solr 4.0 build only.
Can index topics and documents as seperate entities and use Solr Join to associate them.
Try applying the [patch](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2272) to the build you are using or use Solr 4.0 build.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to Jayendra's advice, I'd recommend first trying to denormalizing your schema. I take it you're searching for 'Documents', so your schema would be designed around 'Document' properties, with Topics being dynamic/multiValued properties in the schema.